# postcss-cssnext not processing output

Tags: postcss, cssnext

I'm trying to setup [postcss-cssnext](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext) and must be missing something because when I run `npm run postcss` my output file is created but it looks like the input file (except for some whitepace differences). My `postcss.config.js` file is being loaded but the features are not processing. What am I missing?

#### postcss.config.js

```
var postcss = require('postcss');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');

postcss([
  cssnext({})
]);
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postcss": "postcss input.css -o output.css"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem solved by exporting to `module.exports`

```
var postcss = require('postcss');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');

module.exports = postcss([
  cssnext({})
]);
```